# Quasar preFetch throws error after few minutes

Tags: webpack, vuex, pm2, quasar-framework, vuex-modules

I've been trying to get preFetch to run on quasar to load opengraph tags for my site. My Vuex store imports an instance of axios named **api**. The action in my vuex store is as follows. The app runs for a few minutes/requests and after a while say 10-15 minutes, i get an error that **res.data** is undefined. Currently i am resolving the error anyways to avoid testers from facing the same issue but i am not sure why the error occurs.

```
fetch(context, currentRoute){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        return api.get(currentRoute.name,{params:{slug:currentRoute.params.slug}})
        .then(res=>{
            context.commit('set',res.data);
            resolve();  
        }).catch(err=>{
            context.commit('set',false);
            resolve(); 
        });
    });            
}
```

Comment: Hi. We have a wonderful community on our Discord server. Please join it and look for help there. Your issue requires a more detailed description in order for us to be able to help you. http://chat.quasar-framework.org

Comment: Could you please tell a more? Where that `fetch` method is? How you passing `currentRoute` parameter? Could you indicate the file name/function of the pasted code?

Comment: The function above is an action from a vuex submodule. It is called in the preFetch hook and everytime the route changes for the component. The currentRoute parameter is passed as an action payload.